# No 'scala-library*.jar' in every new IntelliJ Scala Project

Tags: scala, intellij-idea

I have installed intelliJ-IDEA 2017.2.5 with scala plugin on Ubuntu 16.04LTS. When I create new scala project and try to run it I get:

> Error:scalac: No 'scala-library*.jar' in Scala compiler classpath in Scala SDK SBT: org.scala-lang:scala-library:2.12.4:jar

I can fix it by going to Project Structure > Libraries, deleting libraries and adding them again.

Is there a way to change default library so I don't have to do this every time I create new project?

Comment: It's annoying. I pay for the IntelliJ IDEA Ultimate and I expect something better. IDEA is full of this type of problems related with Scala. Sometimes, thinking to return to Eclipse!

Comment: @angelcervera in this specific case the issue is probably not with IntelliJ IDEA, but with SBT: https://github.com/sbt/sbt/issues/3560

Comment: @CrazyCoder I'm sorry if this is not the case, but I am so cranky with all the time that I expend with working around. Sometimes I try to help,
 for example https://stackoverflow.com/questions/41564915/why-could-not-find-implicit-error-in-scala-intellij-scalatest-scalactic but BUG still open.

Comment: Thanks @motek96 for providing the answer right here in your question.

Comment: Interestingly, I  had  issues only for the project _open_ during the upgrade (from 2017.3.3 to 3.4).  Also I managed to get the git version of this project to work, after some hassle.

Comment: Upgrading IntelliJ to 2018.3.* solved this for me.

Answer (score 40, accepted):

If you are using sbt 1.0.2, this problem might be due to a bug in sbt. A fix is expected for sbt 1.0.3.

Related issues:

- https://youtrack.jetbrains.com/issue/SCL-12591
- https://github.com/sbt/sbt/issues/3560

Possible workarounds:

- configure Scala version 2.12.3
- OR downgrade to sbt 0.13.16

Comment: And the 1.0.3 version was released since this answer has been posted and can be found here 
https://developer.lightbend.com/blog/2017-10-27-sbt-1-0-3-hotfix/

Comment: I upgraded my project to sbt 1.0.3 and the Scala plugin to 2017.3.10. Sadly this didn't fix the problem for me.

Answer (score 18):

Select checkbox "Use SBT shell for build and import" in Idea SBT settings. It might help.

Comment: It worked this time, but what actually is happening? Why this has fixed the issue?

Answer (score 1):

In my case upgrading the Scala plugin via IntelliJ options made the trick.

It could be related to a fixed issue.

Go to Preferences, filter on Scala. (Plugins - Scala) click on Update. Restart IntelliJ.

Answer (score 1):

**Switching from scala 2.12.2 to 2.12.3 fixed this** for me.

I too had this problem using IntelliJ 2017.2.4.  My `build.sbt` (originating from the "play-scala-starter-example" project) contained:

```
scalaVersion := "2.12.2"
```

I changed this to:

```
scalaVersion := "2.12.3"
```

And then completed a 'Refresh project'.

I did this after noticing that when I added the most current Scala SDK: scala-sdk-**2.12.3** - (File->Project Structure->Modules, select 'root' and 'Dependencies' tab, then add library), and then I moved it to nearly the first position in the classpath, that I passed SBT: org.scala-lang:scala-library:**2.12.2**:jar along the way.  Being first in the classpath, the "No 'scala-library*.jar' in Scala compiler classpath ..." message disappeared.

Answer (score 0):

Just upgraded 2017.3.3 to 2017.3.4 on sbt 1.0.3 and Scala 2.12.4. Basically,  same s*#t again. In my case  it was  the   warning "Skipping scala files without a scala sdk" for each module after project rebuild.

However, it was only an issue  for the sbt project *open* during the update, whereas the other projects worked fine afterwards. For the broken project, I  finally got its checked-out version from git to work (after "invalidate caches" and other hassle.)

So these steps  may hopefully  save  future trouble:

1. Add the relevant project config files to VC
2. Commit project
3. Close project
4. Upgrade