# IntelliJ `No 'scala-library*.jar' in Scala compiler classpath in Scala SDK Maven: org.scala-lang:scala-library:2.12.7`

Tags: java, scala, maven, intellij-idea

```
scalac: No 'scala-library*.jar' in Scala compiler classpath in Scala SDK Maven: org.scala-lang:scala-library:2.12.7
```

I'm working on a large existing project that uses Java 8 + Scala 2.12.7 with Maven for build. I want to use the IntelliJ Ultimate IDE, version 2023.1.2 which is the current version as of this writing, to work on the project.

This project builds successfully with this command in a shell window:

```
mvn clean install -Dfast -DskipTests=true -Dscala-2.12
```

In IntelliJ Project Structure -> Platform Settings -> Global Libraries, I've downloaded scala-sdk-2.12.7. There are no other Global Libraries configured.

I see related stackoverflow threads like this one ([No 'scala-library*.jar' in every new IntelliJ Scala Project](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/46827010/no-scala-library-jar-in-every-new-intellij-scala-project/46831548#46831548)) but that is years ago and while it's the same error message, the answers aren't helpful and most aren't applicable. I'm not using SBT. And I can't just upgrade to a newer Scala as this is a large legacy project.

I've also done "Rebuild Project" and "Invalidate Caches..." (with restart) several times.

Comment: Try to delete `.idea` directory and [re-import the project](https://www.jetbrains.com/help/idea/maven-support.html#maven_import_project_start). All the dependencies should be configured automatically. If the issue persists, [file a bug](https://youtrack.jetbrains.com/newIssue?project=IDEA) with the [Minimal, Complete, and Verifiable example](https://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve) attached.

Comment: @CrazyCoder, wow that fixed it! I normally try that. Do you want to make that an answer or should I just delete this thread?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The common workaround/fix for such problems is to delete `.idea` directory from the project root and [re-import the project](https://www.jetbrains.com/help/idea/maven-support.html#maven_import_project_start) from the build file.