# Why won't scalatest compile?

Tags: scala, scalatest

I have a simple test setup like

```
package unit

import net.kolotyluk.leaderboard.scorekeeping._
import net.kolotyluk.leaderboard.telemetry.Metrics
import net.kolotyluk.scala.extras.Logging
import org.scalatest.{FlatSpec, GivenWhenThen, Matchers, SequentialNestedSuiteExecution}

import scala.collection.mutable.ArrayBuffer
import scala.concurrent.{Await,Future}
import scala.concurrent.duration._
import scala.concurrent.ExecutionContext.Implicits.global
import scala.util.{Failure, Random, Success}

class LeaderboardSpec
  extends FlatSpec
    with SequentialNestedSuiteExecution
    with GivenWhenThen
    with Matchers
    with Logging {

  behavior of "Leaderboard"

  it must "handle initial conditions correctly" in {
```

but when I try to compile my tests I get 53 errors like

```
[IJ]sbt:leaderboard> test
[info] Compiling 1 Scala source to C:\Users\ERIC\Documents\git\repos\leaderboard\target\scala-2.12\test-classes ...
[error] C:\Users\ERIC\Documents\git\repos\leaderboard\src\test\scala\unit\LeaderboardSpec.scala:21:12: could not find implicit value for parameter pos: org.scalactic.source.Position
[error]   behavior of "Leaderboard"
[error]            ^
```

Which does not actually convey any useful information on what the problem is. I can only assume that something is not configured correctly, either in my build.sbt file, or somewhere else.

This code did work at one time, and somewhere along the way I was cleaning things up, things changed, and now it's broken with no good diagnostics.

Can anyone suggest things to look for?

Comment: this is similar to https://stackoverflow.com/questions/41564915

Comment: Similar yes, but the problem happens outside of IntelliJ, from sbt on the command line. Reviewing stuff now...

Comment: See also https://github.com/kolotyluk/leaderboard

Comment: Nothing in https://stackoverflow.com/questions/41564915 works for me.

Answer (score 1):

So one workaround that seems to compile and run correctly is to stop using SBT and use Maven instead.

I think this is the third major defect I have found in SBT so far.